# Can a TFS test controller only work for one project collection?

Tags: testing, tfs

Is a TFS test controller only bound to one project collection? If I have more project collections, what should I do, install more test controller servers?

Answer (score 1):

Correct. You can only associate one Test Controller to one Team Project Collection. If you want each Project Collection to have a Test Controller, you need to have at least one machine (with the Test Controller service installed) for each collection.

Note, this does not mean it is a one-to-one relationship. You can have multiple Test Controllers per Team Project Collection.